# Why RSpec runs examples in the order not as they're declared?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm using RSpec 2.99 and have the following simple spec file:

```
describe 'thing' do

  context 'context' do
    it 'one thing' do
      # ...
    end

    it 'another thing' do
      # ...
    end
  end

  it 'without context' do
    # ...
  end

end
```

The output was:

```
$ bundle exec rspec test_spec.rb -fd

thing
  without context
  context
    one thing
    another thing

Finished in 0.00092 seconds
3 examples, 0 failures
```

I can't figure out why `without context` goes *before* `context`.

It contradicts with what's written in the documentation for [`--order`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-99/docs/command-line/order-new-in-rspec-core-2-8):

> [...] executes groups and examples in the order they are defined [...]

What am I missing here?

**Update**: on the same documentation page there's a notion:

> Nested groups are always run from top-level to bottom-level [...]

Is this applicable in the given case? If so, it turns out I can't make RSpec to run examples *precisely* as they go in a spec file (leave aside the question why would I need it).

Comment: Same with RSpec 3, the documentation seems to be wrong.

Comment: Your update applies only to `rand` order.

Comment: Maybe, not totally wrong, but not clear enough instead.

Comment: I think you should [file a bug report](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues).

Comment: You already did! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is inaccurate.  When an example group runs, it first [runs its examples](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/v3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb#L453), then [recursively delegates to each of its child example groups](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/v3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb#L454).  This means that the examples of a group will always run before its nested example groups, even if some nested group were defined first.

However, with `--order defined`, the items within each category will be run in defined order.

This is a subtlety that we didn't bear in mind when writing the docs (or even when naming the `--order defined` option).

As for what we should do about it...I'm going to put some thoughts about that on [the issue you opened](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/1756).